# Can Svelte be used with ScrollMagic + GSAP

Tags: svelte, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm having troubles with getting Svelte to work alongside ScrollMagic & GSAP. I've tried looking into it all day and still can't find a solution. Does it even work with Svelte and is there any Svelte & ScrollMagic templates out there?

Thanks.

Comment: We at GreenSock don't recommend using ScrollMagic and instead recommend the official GSAP scroll plugin called [ScrollTrigger](http://greensock.com/scrolltrigger).

Comment: Probably too late, but anyone thinking of using ScrollMagic should take a look at issue tracker on github. Wish I knew how many mobile blockers ScrollMagic has before using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used these instructions as a reference: https://greensock.com/scrollmagic/

In your svelte project add `scrollmagic`, `gsap`, and `scrollmagic-plugin-gsap`:

```
yarn add -D scrollmagic gsap scrollmagic-plugin-gsap
```

Inside `main.js`, configure ScrollMagic to use GSAP:

```js
import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'
import gsap from 'gsap'
import { ScrollMagicPluginGsap } from 'scrollmagic-plugin-gsap'

ScrollMagicPluginGsap(ScrollMagic, gsap)
```

Then in your Svelte component you can define a controller, timeline and screen:

```html
<!--- App.svelte -->
<!-- Copied from example here: https://greensock.com/scrollmagic/ -->
<script>
  import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'
  import { TimelineMax } from 'gsap'
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'

  // define a controller and timeline
  const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller()
  const tl = new TimelineMax()

  // after component mounts, setup scene
  onMount(() => {
    // configure timeline
    tl.staggerFrom(".box", 1.5, {
      scale: 0,
      cycle: {
        y: [-50, 50]
      },
      stagger: {
        from: "center",
        amount: 0.75
      }
    })

    // define the scene
    const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: "#stage",
      duration: "50%",
      triggerHook: 0.35
    })

    scene.setTween(tl)
    scene.addTo(controller)
  })
</script>


<div class="spacer">
  <h1>This section is just a spacer</h1>
</div>

<div id="stage">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
</div>

<div class="spacer">
  <h1>This section is just a spacer</h1>
</div>

<style>
  :global(body) {
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }

  h1 {
    color:white;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #stage{
    height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #262626;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

  }

  .spacer{
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background:#5386b2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .box {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

  }

  .box1 {
    background-color: #84c186;
  }

  .box2 {
    background-color: #8b6c4c;
  }

  .box3 {
    background-color: #39a3ee;
  }

  .box4 {
    background-color: #ef9144;
  }

  .box5 {
    background-color: #cd58eb;
  }

  .box6 {
    background-color: #b84b4b;
  }
</style>
```

It also works in Svelte's REPL using CDN imports: https://svelte.dev/repl/af0b5d29ca624171941be9fe9574c4f3?version=3.22.2

Comment: Very nice, upvoted. For the REPL version to work, I had to comment/uncomment both `controller` and `tl` variables definitions, the original compilation after a fresh load or a page refresh failed. I tried moving both definitions inside `onMount` but the behavior was the same. I'm guessing this is a REPL issue with CDNs.

Comment: We at GreenSock recommend using GSAP 3 formatting. For more info see [this post](http://greensock.com/mistakes).

Comment: Is it possible to install GSAP into a Svelte app by just using CDN links and not npm/yarn installations? Or is npm/yarn required?